# Sorting MySQL table rows by a favorites table

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, favorites

I have an advanced mysql query already. Filtering the results by user favorited uploads, search keywords and date range.

Now I need to add another ordering ontop of this. I want to order this whole thing by most favorites. Most favorites are calculated by counting the occurence of the upload_ids in the favorites table. It should be ordered by most favorites, last_update.

I have looked into the COUNT() element for mysql query, but it's hard to understand how I get it in this already advanced statement construct... Also because the most favorite thing goes on in another table.

I have three mysql tables:
+ user (id,date,user,pass)
+ uploads (id,user_id,date,last_update,description,tags,online_state)
+ favorites (id,date,user_id,upload_id)

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE online_state = 1';//select all online uploads



//FILTER FAVORITES //$favorites_ids are the favorites of the logged in user, being queried in another statement

if  ($upload_display_sort == 'favorites')

$query .= ' AND id IN ('.implode(',', $favorites_ids).')';//returns 1,2,3,4,5



//FILTER SEARCH

if  (   isset($_GET['tags'])    )

$query .= ' AND MATCH (description,tags) AGAINST ("'.urldecode($_GET['tags']).'")';



//FILTER DATE

if  (   isset($_GET['timeframe'])

    and (   $_GET['timeframe'] == '3days'

        or  $_GET['timeframe'] == '2weeks'

        or  $_GET['timeframe'] == '3months')    )

{

    $end_date = time();//current time in unix format

    switch  (   $_GET['timeframe']  )

    {
        case '3days':   $start_date = strtotime('-3 days',$end_date);   break;
        case '2weeks':  $start_date = strtotime('-2 weeks',$end_date);  break;
        case '3months': $start_date = strtotime('-3 months',$end_date); break;
        default:        $start_date = strtotime('');    break;//1970-01-01 01:00:00
    }

    $end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $end_date);//current time in mysql format

    $start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_date);//end time in mysql format

    $query .= ' AND last_update BETWEEN "'.$start_date.'" AND "'.$end_date.'"';

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to count the number of favorites per upload id.  You can do this with an aggregation and join:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM uploads u left outer join
     (select upload_id, count(*) as num
      from favorites f
      group by upload_id
     ) f
     on u.id = f.upload_id
WHERE online_state = 1
```

Then, at the end of your query, add:

```
ORDER BY f.num desc
```

to get the ordering that you want.  Note that the order of SQL statements is important, so the `order by` has to go after the `where`.

Comment: Yes, the favorites table holds the favorisation links between uploads and users. And I need to count the upload ids with the most favorites (user_ids) - so the upload_id which occurs in the favorites table the most is the most popular. And need to order the uploads table by that.

Comment: @handle . . . That was my interpretation and that is what the solution should do.

Comment: I have updated my code with yours, but it does not seem to work. Also I would like to understand what exactly is happening. Could you explain this bplease. Here is what I added at the first query variable definition:  $query = 'SELECT u.* FROM uploads u left outer join '.
    '(SELECT upload_id, COUNT(*) AS num FROM favorites f '.
    'GROUP BY upload_id) f ON u.id = f.upload_id '.
    'WHERE online_state = 1';//select all online uploads

Comment: And I updated the last line to: $query .= ' ORDER BY f.num DESC, last_update DESC';

Comment: I have one upload in my favorites table which is faved most. But it does not show up first in the result. I am trying to build this thing on http://sqlfiddle.com/ - maybe this helps me.

Comment: @Handle . . . No.  From what I understand, the query should do what you want.  Let me know when you have the SQL Fiddle ready.

Comment: I have the sql fiddle, and it works as expected. Outputtin the upload with the most favorites first http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947396/1/0  - Tough I do not see why it does not work for my code - maybe something inbetween is interacting? I do not have the other filters of my code in the sql fiddle because of missing variables.

Comment: @handle . . . presumably, the other conditions filter out the rows you want to see.

Comment: I have used the wrong php file actually :) I have put it in the correct one and it works now. Thanks. Tough I would prefer also understanding what happened in this script :) I am not sure if the result still has all the columns I need (all those from each upload in the uploads table).

Comment: I have updated the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/947396/6/0  -there it also works with some of my other filters but without the text search. Could you add comments what exactly that stuff does? I have tried to understand it myself, tough it is not that clear.